# select time part

Tags: sql, sybase

i need to seperate the time part and date part in different columns. How i can select the date part and time part seprately from a datetime column in sybase?

```
For eg:

My Column has 09-04-2012 10:46:09

 i need "09-04-2012" and  "10:46:09"
```

how it is possible in sybase?

Comment: [check this link ](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks36.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select convert(char(10), cob , 23) from tab

will give you yyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 2):

Don't know much of Sybase, but this should work:

```
select dateformat(column, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), dateformat(column, 'hh:mm:ss') from tab
```

Answer (score 1):

Firends, i found a solution..

Thanks Mostacho,

Actually i am checking with the SqlDBBox tool.. so dateformat method is not supporting. So i used the follwing convertion method.. Its wrking fine.

```
select convert(char(8),getdate(),8)

select convert(char(8),getdate(),5)
```

This is giving me the required output.